# Location of cube in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

The output of this code is 25 cubs rotating .
The problem that I'm facing is the location of each cubes I don not know how to make them be in one line ,  Like for example every 5 cubes in one line and so on.

Note : I have added the Positions of cubes.

```cpp
glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
    glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
    glm::vec3(2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
    glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
    glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
    glm::vec3(2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
    glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
    glm::vec3(1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
    glm::vec3(1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
    glm::vec3(1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
    glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f)
};
```

```cpp
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow))
{
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Camera transformation
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)WIDTH / (float)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));

    //Get uniform locations
    GLint viewlLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewlLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    GLint projlLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projlLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    // Call Shader Program
    ourShader.Use();

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);
        float angle = 20.0f * i;
        angle = glfwGetTime() * 25.0f;
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: What is `cubePositions[i]` into the computing line of the translation matrix `model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`glm::translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284) to add a translation to the model matrix of each individual cube, dependent on the index of the cube. e.g.:

```cpp
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    float dist = ; // distance between the cubes
    float x = (i % 5) * dist;
    float y = (i / 5) * dist;

    float angle = 20.0f * i;
    angle = glfwGetTime() * 25.0f;

    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vector3(x, y, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));

    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}
```

Note, you've to define the distance (`dist`) between the cubes.

---

Note, the concatenation (multiplication `*`) of matrices is not [`Commutative`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).
If you want to rotate the entire block of cubes, then you've to do the translation before the rotation:

```
model = rotate * translate
```

Since [`glm::rotate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaee9e865eaa9776370996da2940873fd4) respectively [`glm::translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284), define a matrix and multiply the input matrix by the new matrix, `glm::rotate` has to be done before `glm::translate`:

```cpp
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vector3(x, y, 0.0f));
```

---

You can use the algorithm to calculate the `cubePositions`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
std::vector<glm::vec3> cubePositions;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    float dist = 5.0f; // distance between the cubes
    float x = (i % 5) * dist;
    float y = (i / 5) * dist;
    cubePositions.push_back(glm::vec3(x, y, 0.0f));
}
```

Comment: I have added the cubePositions[i] to make it more clear .

Comment: @Noura Please read the answer. You've to calculate the positions of the cubes dependent on it's index. Don't use your confused `cubePositions`.  But you can calculate the positions of the cubes. See the last section of the answer, which I've added right now.